# Is an eigenfunction a probability density?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is an eigenfunction in quantum mechanics is simply a probability density that gives a specific eigenvalue?

Comment: An eigen function is a probability "amplitude", not density.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as “a probability density to give a specific eigenvalue”; in fact this is in a sense self contradictory as a probability density implies there is a distribution of outcomes rather than a specific one.

When the system is described by the eigenfunction of an operator, there is 100% probability that the measurement of the observable associated with this operator will produce the outcome $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue associated with the eigenfunction.

Moreover eigenfunctions can be complex functions (think of the spherical harmonics), and so cannot be a probability or probability density es, which must be real.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify things by working in the position basis, and work with energy eigenfunctions. Then consider an energy eigenfunction $\phi_{E, \alpha}(x)$, where $E$ is the energy eigenvalue associated with this eigenfunction (in other words, $\hat{H}\phi_{E, \alpha}(x)=E\phi_{E, \alpha}(x)$, where $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian), and $\alpha$ is an index that specifies other properties of the state (such as the angular momentum quantum numbers, for Hydrogen). I'll also assume all states are normalized.

Then:

- If the state of the system is $\phi_{E, \alpha}$, then $|\phi_{E, \alpha}(x)|^2$ is the probability density of measuring a particle at position $x$. (so in a sense, an eigenfunction *written in the position basis* gives you a probability density for position -- just like any wavefunction).
- If the state of the system is $\phi_{E, \alpha}$, then we will measure the energy to be $E$ with probability $1$. (in this sense, it doesn't make much sense to talk about "the probability" of an eigenfunction).
- A general state can be expanded in terms of the $\phi_{E, \alpha}$ basis as
  \begin{equation}
  \Psi(x) = \int dE \sum_\alpha c_{E, \alpha} \phi_{E, \alpha}(x)
  \end{equation}
  where $c_{E, \alpha}$ are complex coefficients, and the sum over $\alpha$ could be either a sum or an index depending on whether the additional eigenvalues besides energy are continuous or discrete. (Similarly, for bound states, the integral over $E$ should be replaced with a sum over the discrete bound states).
- For a general state $\Psi$, $|\Psi(x)|^2$ is the probability density of measuring the particle at position $x$.
- For a general state $\Psi$, $|c_{E, \alpha}|^2$ is the probability density (for continuous energies or $\alpha$ values) or probability (for discrete energies and $\alpha$ values) of measuring the state to $\phi_{E, \alpha}$.
- For a general state $\Psi$, $\sum_\alpha |c_{E, \alpha}|^2$ is the probability density (for continuous $E$) or probability (for discrete $E$) to measure the energy to be $E$.

You can generalize the above statements to work with any basis (not just the position basis) -- for example you can replace $x$ by $p$ and analogous statements hold for momentum instead of position -- and you can use eigenstates associated with any operator, not just the Hamiltonian.